# CakePHPのこの簡単なコードの、何が違うか分かりますか?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

初めまして！

現在CakePHPのFormコードを利用して、変数$user(整数)をItemテーブルのwhomカラム(int)に追加しようと考えています。

そこで以下のコードを書いてみると、

```
echo $this->Form->hidden($user, array('name' => $this->request->data['Item']['whom']));
```

> Column 'whom' cannot be null

と表示されてしまい、上手く格納出来ていない状況です。

もし何かご存知の方はご教授ください！！

よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('whom', array('value' => $user));
```

でいかがでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます！

無事解決しました！！

Comment: @shinob これは強制ではありませんが、解決できた場合には他の回答者が見たときに「この問題は解決できていますよ」という意思表示のため、この回答に対してチェックしてあげてください。[ツアー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour) をみるとやり方が書いてあります。ご参考までに。